# Socket doesn't work over same network on different devices

Tags: python, sockets, networking, dart, network-programming

When I try to run the client on android emu on the PC I've hosted my socket server on. The connection does work but when I try to run the client app on practical devices, It neither connects nor throws any error. I tried disabling the firewall and that didn't work either.

Here's my server socket code in python:

```
import socket
import json

from test import testdef

HEADERSIZE = 10
SERVER = "0.0.0.0" # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDR)
s.listen(5)
print(f"[ACTIVE] Hosted on {SERVER}")
print(f"[CONNECT TO] {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}")

while True:
    client_socket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"[CONNECTED] {address}")
    header = b''
    while len(header) < HEADERSIZE:
        chunk = client_socket.recv(HEADERSIZE - len(header))
        if chunk == b'':
            break
        header += chunk

    if len(header) < HEADERSIZE:
        print("Client disconnected without sending full header")
        continue

    payload_len = int(header)
    payload = b''
    while len(payload) < payload_len:

    chunk = client_socket.recv(payload_len - len(payload))
    if chunk == b'':
        break
    payload += chunk

if len(payload) < payload_len:
    print("Client disconnected without sending full payload")
    continue

payload = payload.decode(FORMAT)
print(f"[REQUEST] {payload}")
request = json.loads(payload)
if request["command"] == "test":
    testdef(request["username"], request["password"])
    send_message = {'status': 'RECEIVED'}
    final_send_message = json.dumps(send_message)
    client_socket.send(bytes(final_send_message, FORMAT))

if request["command"] == "createAccount":
    send_message = {'status': 'RECEIVED'}
    final_send_message = json.dumps(send_message)
    client_socket.send(bytes(final_send_message, FORMAT))
```

Here's my dart client code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

Map _response;

Future<Map> request(Map requestJson) async {
  Socket _socket;
  await Socket.connect("192.168.56.1", 5050).then((Socket sock) {
    _socket = sock;
  }).then((_) {

    final _payload = jsonEncode(requestJson);
    int _header = 8;
    int _msgLength = _payload.length;
    final _finalMessage = _msgLength.toString() + (" " * _header) + _payload;

    _socket.write(_finalMessage);
    return _socket.first;
  }).then((data) {
    _response = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(data));
  });
  return _response;
}
```

Comment: they are not in the same network

Comment: but my pc where I'm hosting the server and my mobile running client app are on the same wifi

Comment: you can check that by pinging your phone

Comment: did it and it was successful. ''' Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 658ms, Average = 248ms'''